# Display GridView while others still load

Tags: asp.net, gridview, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, backgroundworker

I am new to ASP.NET/C#. Recently I came across the `asp:UpdatePanel` control in ASP.NET. I have multiple GridViews in a page. What I am trying to achieve is to display the GridViews as and when they are loaded.

Say for instance, the first GridView data is loaded from the data source and is databound to the Grid. How can I use an `UpdatePanel` to show the results to the user while the other GridViews are still being loaded?

Note:
To achieve this, I am currently using a flag and a timer. The timer is set as a `Trigger` in the `UpdatePanel` On every `Tick` of the timer, I check if the data is loaded using the flag. If so, I call the `DataBind()` method which then displays the data on the page while the others are still being processed.

I know the above is not the most efficient way to do this. Please help.

Comment: Is there a way to update the panel from the code behind after the `DataBind()` method is called?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the update mode of `Updatepanel` to `Conditional`, after `DataBind()` you should call `.Update()`
 such as

```
GridView1.DataBind();
UpdatePanel1.Update();
```

Comment: I tried that. To amplify my point. There are 4 `BackgroundWorkers` that I make use of. In each BW, I query the database for each of the 4 `GridViews`. In the `RunWorkerCompletedMethod`, I first bind the data using `GridView.DataBind()` followed by `UpdatePanel.Update()`. However, the data is not shown on the page until all 4 complete (i.e., the page postsback)

Comment: As I also mentioned, if I register a `asp:Timer` as a trigger in the `UpdatePanel` and call the `DataBind()` method inside it, it updates the page with the results while the other 3 are still being loaded. However, polling is not an efficient solution to any problem.